# "error: expected identifier before numeric constant " in generated c file

Tags: c

I'm trying to build my code base and I got the error

> "error: expected identifier before numeric constant "

in generated c file  while building

and the line number refers to  rw_offsetof( struct __pthread_mutex_s, 1 ),

```
sizeof( pthread_attr_t ),
sizeof(((pthread_attr_t *)RW_UE_NULL)->__size ),
sizeof( struct __pthread_internal_slist ),
rw_offsetof( struct __pthread_internal_slist, __next ),
sizeof( struct __pthread_mutex_s ),
rw_offsetof( struct __pthread_mutex_s, __lock ),
rw_offsetof( struct __pthread_mutex_s, __count ),
rw_offsetof( struct __pthread_mutex_s, __owner ),
rw_offsetof( struct __pthread_mutex_s, __kind ),
rw_offsetof( struct __pthread_mutex_s, __nusers ),
rw_offsetof( struct __pthread_mutex_s, 1 ),
sizeof( pthread_mutex_t ),
sizeof(((pthread_mutex_t *)RW_UE_NULL)->__size ),
sizeof( pthread_mutexattr_t ),
sizeof(((pthread_mutexattr_t *)RW_UE_NULL)->__size ),
sizeof( pthread_cond_t ),
sizeof(((pthread_cond_t *)RW_UE_NULL)->__size ),
sizeof( pthread_condattr_t ),
sizeof(((pthread_condattr_t *)RW_UE_NULL)->__size ),
sizeof( sem_t ),
sizeof(((sem_t *)RW_UE_NULL)->__size ),
```

I found  __pthread_mutex_s is defined in pthreadtypes.h

```
typedef union  
{  
  struct  __pthread_mutex_s  
  {  
    int __lock;  
    unsigned int __count;  
    int __owner;  
    int __kind;  
    unsigned int __nusers;  
    __extension__ union  
    {  
      int __spins;  
      __pthread_slist_t __list;  
    };  
  } __data;  
  char __size[__SIZEOF_PTHREAD_MUTEX_T];  
  long int __align;  
} pthread_mutex_t;
```

as this is system file, how this can cause problem ??

Comment: above code is not sufficient to point out the error

Comment: Please show enough of the generated code and exactly this code (without any modifications)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter to `rw_offsetof` should be the name of a field within the struct named in the first parameter. The usage in line 1367 looks correct, but in line 1368 you have the literal constant `1` instead of the name of a field, hence the error.

Without any more context it's hard to tell how this error occurred, but my best guess would be that you have a preprocessor macro somewhere with the same name as a field in `__pthread_mutex_s` (e.g. `__count` or `__list`), and this macro is `#define`d as `1`.

Comment: thanks for the reply.. I found  __pthread_mutex_s is defined in pthreadtypes.h

typedef union  
{  
  struct __pthread_mutex_s  
  {  
    int __lock;  
    unsigned int __count;  
    int __owner;  
    int __kind;  
    unsigned int __nusers;  
    __extension__ union  
    {  
      int __spins;  
      __pthread_slist_t __list;  
    };  
  } __data;  
  char __size[__SIZEOF_PTHREAD_MUTEX_T];  
  long int __align;  
} pthread_mutex_t;  

as this is system file, how this can cause problem ??

Comment: Re-read what I wrote in my answer above - you may have defined a preprocessor macro somewhere, where the macro has the same name as one of the fields in this struct.

Comment: but here sixth element in struct __pthread_mutex_s is having issue and sixth element is a union and there is no name for it.

 was that creating the problem?

Comment: Who knows - it could be something to do with the anonymous union but you haven't provided enough information for anyone to diagnose this - you need to look at how this code is being generated and see if maybe it's a problem with a preprocessor macro or something else.

Comment: I commented out that line and proceeded, now build is done.